# How to add prepared control to wrappanel dynamically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I prepared a Material Design Card which has Grid, StackPanel, Button etc. I would like to add it dynamically in to wrap panel in WPF. Adding a single control, like button, is easy and I know how to do it. But when it comes to adding a control which has another controls inside I don't want to create them one by one programmatically and add wrap panel.

```
<materialDesign:Card x:Key="PDFThumbnail" x:Name="PDFThumbnail" 
 Margin="3,3,0,0" Width="200">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image      
      Height="140"
      Width="196"
      Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                <StackPanel
      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
      Grid.Row="2"
      Orientation="Horizontal"
      Margin="8">
                    <Button
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}"
        Width="30"
        Padding="2 0 2 0"
        materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsCentered="True">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon
          Kind="Delete" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
```

I would like to name the material design card and add it to wrap panel as if it was a single control.

Comment: `wrapPanel.Children.Add(Resources["PDFThumbnail"] as Card);`?

Comment: @mm8 I tried and It works but I cannot add the second or third one. It allows me adding only one by showing this error: "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.". Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: Set `x:Shared="False"` on the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have defined the `Card` as a resource, you could just retrieve the resource and cast it before you add it to the `WrapPanel`:

```
wrapPanel.Children.Add(Resources["PDFThumbnail"] as Card);
```

If you want to be able to resuse the same `Card`, you should also set the [`x:Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute) attribute to `false`:

```
<materialDesign:Card x:Key="PDFThumbnail" x:Shared="False" Margin="3,3,0,0" Width="200">
```

Comment: Yes... this one also is working.. I am going to use it durong drag & drop pdf files into wrappanel and show pdf capture pic. Card will have a delete button to remove that card itrem from wrappanel. I cannot reach the image and stackpanel control inside the Card by this way. How can I do it? also I don't want to remove all cards from wrappanel when I click on "Delete" button on each card, for that, I specify a Name for the cards before adding them? What do you think? Have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: @EmreKadan: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question was about how to add the `Card` to a `WrapPanel` and nothing else.